# How do you evaluate continuity for a g(x) function with given conditions?

Tags: calculus

Given $g(x)$ such that

$ \frac{af(x)}{(x^2-5x+6)}+4x$  if $x<2$ and

2 if  $ x=2$

$\frac{bf(x)}{sin(x-2)}+a$ if $ x>2$

Find the values for continuity with the given conditions:

Condition 1:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\frac{f(x)}{x-2}=6$$

And  condition 2:

$$f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow x=2$$

Here is what I've tried by myself:
Left side:
 $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} 
 \frac{af(x)}{(x^2-5x+6)}+4x=$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} 
 \frac{a}{(x-3)} \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} 
 \frac{f(x)}{(x-2)}+\lim_{x\rightarrow 2^-}4x=$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-} 
 \frac{a6}{(x-3)} +4x= $$ 
$$-6a+8$$
How do you consider the other condition for the right side to evaluate continuity? I think that I could do it  like the following :
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+} 
 f(x)= 0$$
but I'm not sure cause it change the whole limit from the right side directly to 0. What do you think?. Suggestions will be welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ g$ is continuous at $ x=2$
if
$$\lim_{2-}g=\lim_{2^+}g=g(2)=2$$

or

$$\lim_{2^-}\frac{af(x)}{(x-2)(x-3)}+8=2$$

and
$$\lim_{2^+}\frac{f(x)(x-2)b}{(x-2)\sin(x-2)}+a=2$$

we get
$$-6a+8=2$$
and
$$6b+a=2$$
thus
$$\boxed{a=1\;\;;\;\;b=\frac 16}$$

Comment: Thank you. I forgot the special limit of sin(x)/x